# .htaccess and url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible somehow using mod_rewrite change the url from `http://www.mywebsite.com/company/123/reviews` to `http://www.mywebsite.com/company-123/reivews`?

It's not a redirect. The problem is that the real path is the first one and I need my browser to display the second path. So when the user goes to `company-123/reviews` the content of the page is displayed from `company/123/reviews`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-z]*?)-([0-9]*?)/([a-z]*?)$ /$1/$2/$3
```

I think this will work, the regex does it's job atleast.

Answer (score 0):

Use this rule to rewrite the former URL path to the latter one:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-([0-9]+)/([^/]+)$ $1/$2/$3 [L]
```

But you already need the former URLs in your documents to get this rewriting work.